# How can we identify the Dynamics CRM web api version in js?

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, dynamics-365, dynamics-crm-365, dynamics-crm-webapi

Can we detect the Web API version in js like v8.0 v8.1 or v9.0, this will help to write supported message calls vs unsupported messages and handle it gracefully?

One way is about querying the CRM version using SDK `RetrieveVersionRequest` & detecting it using mapping like CRM 365 means v9.0 etc.

Any direct way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use `Xrm.Page.context.getVersion`
more details on my blog post

[Xrm.Page.context.getVersion is now a supported method, use it!](http://www.crmanswers.net/2017/05/xrmpagecontextgetversion-is-now.html)